# modify the brightness of a an image in a non-homogeneous

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, pixel

Is there anyway to modify the brightness of a an image in a non-homogeneous way? I mean that every pixel of an image is modified with different magnitude.I am using python's function pillow. I dont mind doing it with Opencv if there is a way.

Comment: You can manually modify every pixel with whatever way you like but it's not really efficient this pixel-wise approach normally.

Comment: I am working with 100 of thousands of images

Comment: Provide some information about the diversity of your desired brightness (all pixels different value etc) and other parameters like image size etc

Comment: Actually a random diversity is fine. I just want to get some part of the image to be darker than the other part.

Comment: Can you please upload a sample input and expected output? Is the input image colored or gray scale? What do you mean by regions in the image?

Comment: You can split your images into patches and apply brightness to those patches then.

Comment: The images are colored images and the expected output to be a darker image but no in a homogeneous way. For example if we consider the image to be 4 quadrants, every quadrant is modified differently

Comment: I gave the example of 4 quadrants better understanding. I actually would prefer to be able to darken every single pixel differently

Comment: Generate an image the same size of random floats all less than one. Multiply your image by it. The result will be darker.

Comment: Mark Setechell, yeah THANK YOU.

Comment: you can use subimages and/or masks for many "not on the whole image" operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV's native format is a numpy array so we are able to do manipulate the image as you want by subtracting (or multiplying fractional values as suggested by @Mark Setchel) by arrays of the same size and shape.

Get the original image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

color_img = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
cv2.imshow("Cat", color_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(color_img.shape)
```

Create your randomized array of the same size and shape:

```
result = np.random.randint(10, 60, size=color_img.shape, dtype='uint8')
```

Convert out of `uint8` to prevent overflows:

```
color_img32 = np.asarray(color_img, dtype="int32")
```

Subtract our array:

```
color_img32 -= result
```

Make sure everything is between 0 and 255 and convert back to `uint8`:

```
color_img32 = np.clip(color_img32, 0, 255)
color_image_u8 = color_img32.astype('uint8')
cv2.imshow("Cat", color_image_u8)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note that with the multiplication method (multiplying by a number between 0 and 1) you don't have to worry about overflow or clipping, just make sure you convert back to `uint8` after multiplying by a `float`.

### Before:

[image: Before]

### After

[image: After]

To convert back to PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(color_image_u8)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this thoroughly explained answer. I multiplied my image with a random array but I cannont show it anymore as I am getting this error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'show'. any thoughts?

Comment: Sure, you need to convert back to a PIL image if you want to use `img.show()`. See my edit, but its just `Image.fromarray`

Comment: I am sorry but any idea how to do it?

Comment: `from PIL import Image` and then
`im = Image.fromarray(color_image_u8)`